# Como sobrescrever variável definida no POM com valor específico no momento da execução do mvn?

Tags: java, maven

Num ambiente com múltiplas configuracoes de Web Container as vezes precisamos apontar corretamente o diretório de deploy da aplicação que pode estar em diretórios diferentes dependendo do Sistema Operacional usado e do gerenciador de pacotes (apt-get no Ubuntu, homebrew no Mac OS, etc.). Além disso poderemos necessitar de instalar mais de um instância da aplicação numa máquina (Teste, Homologação, Produção, etc). Para isso precisamos sobrescrever uma certa propriedade definida no POM que aponta para o diretorio de deploy.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso ?

Comment: oi @joao-parana não sou obrigado a usar Profile no POM, certo ? No caso de usar como seria neste seu exemplo ?

Comment: editei a resposta e coloquei o profile. Não é necessário usar profile mas num trabalho em grupo pode ajudar na fatoração dos arquivos de configuração de Build via Maven (POM pai, POM filho, settings.xml, etc)

Answer (score 3):

Para sobrescrever uma propriedade definida no POM use o `parâmetro -D` típico de qualquer aplicativo Java quando invocar o `mvn`

Por exemplo para fazer o deploy de ativos compartilhados pelas aplicações para um diretório de TESTE :

```
mvn -P deployShared package  -Dshared_dir=/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.47/shared
```

Neste exemplo estamos sobrescrevendo shared_dir durante a fase de package. Esta variavel é usada pelo profile deployShared definido no POM para copiar os arquivos para o ambiente Tomcat (versão 7.0.47) usado para **Teste**.

O mesmo POM pode ser usado para fazer deploy para o ambiente de **Homologação** da seguinte forma:

```
mvn -P deployShared package -Dshared_dir=/usr/local/tomcat-7.0.47-homolog/shared
```

E assim por diante.

O profile `deployShared`  usa o `maven-dependency-plugin` e ficaria assim:

```
    <profile>
        <id>deployShared</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                                <outputDirectory>${shared_dir}</outputDirectory>
                                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${shared_dir}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```